# CSS adaptive layout

Tags: html, css

I created a gallery from instagram, my script loads username, caption, image url, profile image. I want to locate this elements as on the picture. But there are difficulties in adaptation to the screen (mobile). How to do it more adaptive? Because i use margin-left, i think it's bad.

[image: Example what i mean]

My code:

```
    <div id="instafeed" class="instafeed">
<div id="instafeed_body">
    <div id="instafeed_main">
    <a id="instafeed_link" target="_blank" href="link"><img id="instafeed_image" src="image_link" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="instafeed_author_block">
    <div class="instafeed_author_wrapper">
    <div class="instafeed_author"><img src="profile_picture" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="instafeed_author_desc">
    <div class="instafeed_item_author_name">username</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and CSS (i remove some stylize code such as border and etc.):

```
.instafeed {
    text-align: center;
}

#instafeed_image {
    width: 40%;
    padding: 8px;
}

.instafeed_author_block {
    padding: 1%;
}

.instafeed_author_wrapper {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.instafeed_author {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 29%;
}

.instafeed_author img {
    width: 72px;
    height: 72px;
    border-radius: 36px;
}

.instafeed_author_desc {
    float: left;
}

.instafeed_item_author_name {
    color: #2c3e50;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
```

Comment: You should consider using a framework such as bootstrap that's made for this. If you're intent on rolling your own though, you may want to check out [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and see how they can be used to target different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

For positioning use the CSS property `position` together with the `right`, `left`, `top` and `bottom` properties, this way you can pinpoint exact locations on your screen as to where you want the element.

**Example:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:black;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:29%;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhzg81t2/)

Read more about this property [here(w3c)](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) or [here(mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

**EDIT**

To get it to be "adaptive" you could take a look at the CSS transform property as well, this goes quite well with the position property as to positioning the element even further like when browsing from a handheld device.

**Example**

**HTML**

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:black;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:29%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

[Fiddle with transform](https://jsfiddle.net/hhzg81t2/1/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it responsive, not adaptive, it's better

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
    <p></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .container{
      width:100%;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }

    .box{
      width:50%;
      height:50px;
      margin:0 25%;
      float:left;
    }

    .image{
       float:left;
      width:100%;
      height:200px;
        background: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
      background-size: 100% 100%;
    }

    .text{
      text-align:center;
    }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6p80opg/)

Image will be stretching (try to resize window), you can adjust it to fit yours image ratio...